# What should be NPM command for solving this question?

Tags: npm, command, package.json

I tried various solutions for this question but not able to pass 2 test cases amongst 4. Please help me crackdown this problem

Perform the below mentioned steps by creating *package.json* file named *npm_commands* in the *maxbot* directory

1. Create a file named *index.js*.
2. Write a js code in *index.js* file to create a string named *myVar* and value as *node package manager*
   and convert it into uppercase.

*NOTE: Please use console.log to display the output of  myVar in index.js file*

2. Configure *scripts* in *package.json*
   (a) to check the versions of npm and node by using `npm run release | tee output1.txt`
   (b) to execute index.js by using `npm run build | tee output.txt`

Comment: Are you asking a community to do your homeworks? This does not look like a simple, clear question

Answer (score 4):

1. npm init - to initialize new package

- give npm_commands as package name
- give index.js as start file

2. Create new file named as index.js

- declare : let myVar = "node package manager"
- print var in uppercase: console.log(myVar.toUpperCase());

3. Add these scripts in package.json

- to check npm and node version: "release": "npm -v && node -v",
- to execute index.js file: "build": "node index.js"

4. Save and then run these commands to get the results:

- npm run release | tee output1.txt
- npm run build | tee output.txt

Comment: damn it man, i missed it to change package_name two times. im not able to understand that. Im still thinking why 75% only coming

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** run the command to initialize new package

> npm init

**Step 2:** Command will start package initialization process

- Set the package name:

> package name: (challange) npm_commands

[image]

[image]

**Step3:** Press enter till time it ask for "entry point", by default it set to index.js verify and press enter key. Until the initialization process ends.

[image]

[image]

**Step 4:** Go to editor project explorer add create new file index.js, and add following code in it.

```
let myVar = 'node package manager';
console.log(myVar.toUpperCase());
```

**Step 5:** Add following lines into script block of package.json file

```
"release" : "npm -v && node -v",
"build" : "node index.js",
```

Script block looks like as below after adding above lines

```
"scripts": {
    "release" : "npm -v && node -v",
    "build" : "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

**Step 6:** Now open the command prompt and run the following commands

```
npm run release | tee output1.txt
npm run build | tee output.txt
```

Above commands create the output1.txt, and output.txt files in project explorer containing respective commands output.

**Step 7:** That's it! now run the test and check your FS_SCORE for 100% and submit the test.